# RichFaces 3: how to apply/change styles for rich:pickList displayed items

Tags: richfaces

I can't figure out how to use the provided in the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_pickList.html#d0e39961) attributes to apply the styles to the displayed items. There is nothing similar n the provided examples where the items are already aligned to the left:
[image]

In my case, I have them centered and would like to left-align. Weird enough, but, there are no styles in the existing code that force align them by center.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution I came to was to add the following to the existing CSS file to override `td` text alignement styles that were set to center-align the text:

```css
.rich-picklist-source-items, .rich-picklist-target-items {
    text-align: left;
}
```